# Can't understand how my solution is leading to double counting.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We want to count all possible 8 coin tosses with at least 3 heads.

I know two correct ways to solve this. One is to simply add up all individual cases of 3 heads, 4 heads and so on upto 8 heads. This results in $$\sum_{i=3}^n \binom{8}{i} = 219$$. Another is to subtract the unwanted cases from all possible cases: $$2^8 - \binom{8}{0} - \binom{8}{1} - \binom{8}{2} = 219$$.

My (incorrect) reasoning is:
Choose 3 tosses out of eight to be heads, and assign heads or tails to the remaining 5 tosses. Leading to the expression: $$\binom{8}{3}\times 2^5 = 1792$$
This is absurd because it is bigger than the possible types of eight coin tosses namely $2^8=256$. Clearly there is double counting. But I can't seem to understand how.

Comment: You are overcounting all the cases with $≥4$ Heads.   Specifically, given a configuration with, say, exactly $4$ Heads, you can't tell which three of those were the special ones you chose first, so you count those cases $4$ times.  Cases with more than $4$ Heads are even worse...if you had, say, exactly $5$ heads then you count each case $\binom 53$ times.

Comment: For example you counted the sequence HHHHHHHH $56$ times.

Comment: Although combinations does establish order, multiplying by $2^5$ certainly doesn't and thus in the end there is no order and thus double (more like multiple) counting happens.

Comment: you counted the sequence HHHHHHHH 56 times - can you please explain how?

Comment: Again, if you have $k≥3$ Heads then you count that case once for every choice of $3$ amongst them, thus you count such a state $\binom k3$ times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the answer from the comment section (where it shouldn't ever have been) into an answer in the answer section (where it belongs).

Look at the sequence HHHHTTTT.

- You counted it once when you picked the first three throws to be dedicated as heads, and then happened to assign heads to only the fourth throw of the remaining five
- You counted it once when you picked the first, the second, and the fourth throws to be dedicated heads, and happened to assign heads to only the third throw of the remaining five
- You counted it once when you picked the first, the third, and the fourth throws to be heads, and happened to assign heads to only the second throw of the remaining five
- You counted it once when you picked the second, the third, and the fourth throws to be heads, and happened to assign heads to only the first throw of the remaining five

In total, this one sequence was counted four times. Sequences with more than four heads were counted even more times.